# check if a dataframe is not empty in 1 line of code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am checking if a dataframe is empty or not but I want to do this in 1 line of code as I am checking many dataframe's and don't want to repeat the same code again as it becomes chunky. example is below. great if anyone can help

```
if not df.empty:
   df['test_col'] = np.nan
else:
   print('data is empty')
```

Comment: Do you want to initialize `df['test_col'] = np.nan` if the frame is empty or is printing the message also important? If you do this a lot, have you thought about creating a little method to support it?

Comment: sorry i should have elaborated a bit more. the column called = test_col will change for each df. for example 1 df the column is called 'basic' and for another df, the column will be called 'standard' and because of this i dont think creating a method will work unless im wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wanted a one-liner

```
df["test_col"] = np.nan if not df.empty else "data is empty"
```

The output is

```
        Apples  Pears   Peaches Grapes  test_col
0       12      23      0       4       NaN
1       10      0       0       4       NaN
2       12      16      12      5       NaN
3       6       0       0       11      NaN
```

What I would do is that I would make it into a function as follows:

```
def check_empty(df):
    df["test_col"] = np.nan if not df.empty else "data is empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do a for loop:

```
list_of_dfs=[df1,df2,df3] # there can be any number of dfs
for x in list_of_dfs:
  if not x.empty:
   x['test_col'] = np.nan
  else:
   print('data is empty')
```

Comment: sorry i should have elaborated a bit more. the column called = test_col will change for each df. for example 1 df the column is called 'basic' and for another df, the column will be called 'standard'.

Comment: @Zack you can use a list of columns and zip list_of_dfs together to use them together.

Comment: Proper answer, but it is not "one line of code"